# API Platform -Serialization groups don't work correctly

Tags: php, api, symfony, serialization

I have a project developped under Symfony 5 and API Platform. However, I encounter a very strange problem. When I add serialization or deserialization groups to my resources and I try to recover a collection or even an item, all the fields do not appear in the response.

That is my resource definition

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *  attributes={"security"="is_granted('ROLE_USER')"},
 *  normalizationContext={
 *      "groups"={"pelerins_read"}
 *  },
 *  collectionOperations={
 *      "get"={"security"="is_granted('ROLE_INSCRIPTION') or is_granted('ROLE_ENCADREUR')", "security_message"="Vous n'êtes autorisés à consulter cette ressource"},
 *      "post"={"security"="is_granted('ROLE_INSCRIPTION')", "security_message"="Vous n'êtes autorisés à consulter cette ressource"}
 *  },
 *  itemOperations={
 *      "get"={"security"="is_granted('ROLE_INSCRIPTION') or is_granted('ROLE_ENCADREUR')"},
 *      "put"={"security"="is_granted('ROLE_INSCRIPTION')"}
 *  }
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PelerinRepository")
 */
class Pelerin
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"pelerins_read", "pelerins_read", "etat_sante_read"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Le nom de famille du pèlerin est recquis.")
     * @Groups({"pelerins_read", "pelerins_read", "etat_sante_read"})
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Le prénom du pèlerin est recquis.")
     * @Groups({"pelerins_read", "pelerins_read", "etat_sante_read"})
     */
    private $prenom;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Le sexe du pèlerin est recquis.")
     * @Assert\Choice(choices={"M", "F"}, message="Le sexe doit un caractère entre M et F")
     * @Groups({"pelerins_read"})
     */
    private $sexe;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="La date de naissance du pèlerin est recquise.")
     * @Groups({"pelerins_read"})
     */
    private $date_naissance;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Le lieu de naissance du pèlerin est recquis.")
     * @Groups({"pelerins_read"})
     */
    private $lieu_naissance;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="La résidence du pèlerin est recquise.")
     * @Groups({"pelerins_read"})
     */
    private $residence;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"pelerins_read"})
     */
    private $numero_telephone;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\Email(message="Le format de l'adresse email saisie n'est pas correct")
     * @Groups({"pelerins_read"})
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"pelerins_read"})
     */
    private $numero_whatsapp;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Le numéro du passeport du pèlerin est recquis")
     * @Groups({"pelerins_read"})
     */
    private $numero_passeport;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="La nature du passeport du pèlerin est recquis")
     * @Groups({"pelerins_read"})
     */
    private $nature_passeport;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Formule", inversedBy="pelerins")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     * @Groups({"pelerins_read"})
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Formule de voyage recquise pour continuer l'opération")
     */
    private $formule;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Groups({"pelerins_read"})
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="La date d'inscription est requise")
     */
    private $date_inscription;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"pelerins_read"})
     */
    private $inscrit_par;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"pelerins_read"})
     */
    private $numero_inscrit_par;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"pelerins_read"})
     */
    private $en_cas_urgence;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"pelerins_read"})
     */
    private $numero_en_cas_urgence;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=500, nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"pelerins_read"})
     */
    private $commentaire;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Groups({"pelerins_read"})
     */
    private $created_at;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     * @Groups({"pelerins_read"})
     */
    private $created_by;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"pelerins_read"})
     */
    private $updated_at;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User")
     * @Groups({"pelerins_read"})
     */
    private $updated_by;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     * @Groups({"pelerins_read"})
     */
    private $is_deleted;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"pelerins_read"})
     */
    private $deleted_at;
```

You can see this picture, only

```
{
  "nom": "string",
  "prenom": "string",
  "sexe": "string",
  "residence": "string",
  "email": "string",
  "formule": "string",
  "commentaire": "string"
}
```

are appearing.

[Result after adding deserialisation groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlyUW.png)

It is the same for serialisation groups. See this picture
[Result after serialization groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WVsi.png)
We have

```
{
            "@id": "/api/pelerins/7",
            "@type": "Pelerin",
            "id": 7,
            "nom": "Knox",
            "prenom": "Tamara",
            "sexe": "M",
            "residence": "Chagai",
            "email": "nunc.id@esttempor.ca",
            "formule": "/api/formules/1",
            "commentaire": null
}
```

So I want to know What can I do to fix this error ?
Thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's solved.
The problem is variables names. It seems that API Platform don't recognize variables underscore in normalizationContext.
look at here https://www.grafikart.fr/forum/topics/32395#p126203